# Color Picker UI for Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I am investigating feasibility of implementing a colour picker (for home automation purposes for example, to pick colour of lights, etc) for an app running on Android Wear.

I could not find any mention of a pre-made UI element like this, am I not looking at the right places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

As quite good for small screen - would be extra cool on Moto 360.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BoD/android-wear-color-picker

This is a color picker designed specifically for Android Wear, and is based off of Lars Werkman's HoloColorPicker.